# How to print unique values in order of appearance?

Tags: bash, unique

I'm trying to get the unique values 
from the list below, but leaving the
 unique values in the original order.

This is, the order of appearance.

```
group
swamp
group
hands
swamp
pipes
group
bellyful
pipes
swamp
emotion
swamp
pipes
bellyful
after
bellyful
```

I've tried combining `sort` and `uniq` commands but the output is sorted alphabetically, and if I don't use sort command, uniq command doesn't work.

```
$ sort file | uniq
after
bellyful
emotion
group
hands
pipes
swamp
```

and my desiree output would be like this

```
group
swamp
hands
pipes
bellyful
emotion
after
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A short, jam-packed awk invocation will get the job done. We'll create an associative array and count every time we've seen a word:

```
$ awk '!count[$0]++' file
group
swamp
hands
pipes
bellyful
emotion
after
```

Explanation:

1. Awk processes the file one line at a time and `$0` is the current line.
2. `count` is an associative array mapping lines to the number of times we've seen them. Awk doesn't mind us accessing uninitialized variables. It automatically makes `count` an array and sets the elements to `0` when we first access them.
3. We increment the count each time we see a particular line.
4. We want the overall expression to evaluate to true the first time we see a word, and false every successive time. When it's true, the line is printed. When it's false, the line is ignored. The first time we see a word `count[$0]` is `0`, and we negate it to `!0 == 1`. If we see the word again `count[$0]` is positive, and negating that gives `0`.
5. Why does true mean the line is printed? The general syntax we're using is `expr { actions; }`. When the expression is true the actions are taken. But the actions can be omitted; the default action if we don't write one is `{ print; }`.

Comment: Amen, and I though `awk '$1 in seen {next} {seen[$1]++}1' file` was jam-packed.